# Error occurs in the template of component TestComponent in Angular

Tags: angular, angular13

Estoy haciendo upgrade de Angular 10 a 13, pero al momento de correr la aplicación me encontré con este problema que me marca error en el template del componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la forma en la que se declara:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe si cambio la forma de implementar el @component para Angular 13? he buscado en la documentación pero veo que la implementación es igual. Les agradezco me pudieran ayudar!

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420966/error-occurs-in-the-template-of-component-uppercasecomponent) te podría ayudar.